# Keep the content of a textView after scrolling the listView

Tags: android, listview

i have a listView and in this listView i have 2 textView that show their content with a long click and hide them with a single click. I have a problem with the scroll. When i show a content with a long click and i scroll down and after i scroll up i see that the content of the textView disappear. How i can keep this content after the scroll? This is my code about the long click:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                final Insegnamento insegnamento = insegnamenti.get(i);
                TextView nomeDoc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomeDocente);
                nomeDoc.setText(R.string.nDocente);
                String nDoc = nomeDoc.getText().toString() + " " + insegnamento.getNomeDoc();
                nomeDoc.setText(nDoc);
                nomeDoc.setTextColor(Color.argb(255,48,63,159));

                TextView cogDoc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cognomeDocente);
                cogDoc.setText(R.string.cDocente);
                String cDoc = cogDoc.getText().toString() + " " + insegnamento.getCognomeDoc();
                cogDoc.setText(cDoc);
                cogDoc.setTextColor(Color.argb(255,48,63,159));
                Toast.makeText(DocActivity.this,R.string.info_doc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                final Insegnamento insegnamento = insegnamenti.get(i);
                TextView nomeDoc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomeDocente);
                nomeDoc.setText("");
                TextView cogDoc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cognomeDocente);
                cogDoc.setText("");
            }
        });
```

This is the code about the listView

```
protected void onPostExecute(String res){
    if(res != null){
        if(response_code==404){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.noIns, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(DocActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(response_code==1000) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.rete, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(DocActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            try{
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(res);
                for ( int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String cognomeDocente = object.getString("docenteCognome");
                    String nomeDocente = object.getString("docenteNome");
                    String insegnamento = object.getJSONObject("chiaveUdContestualizzata").getString("udDes");
                    String codiceInsegnamento = object.getJSONObject("chiaveUdContestualizzata").getString("udCod");
                    Insegnamento ins = new Insegnamento(nomeDocente,cognomeDocente,codiceInsegnamento,insegnamento);
                    insegnamenti.add(ins);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ListAdapter adapter;
        adapter = new ListAdapter(DocActivity.this, insegnamenti);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Thank you

Comment: use recyclerview instead and override getItemViewType by returning seperate view flag for unlocked content textviews.
refer : https://android.jlelse.eu/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-dfba3979050

Comment: One requirement is that i must use a default adapter but i use a custom adapter. i can't use this recyclerview because i need my custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

In your Insegnamento object model add a field let say :

```
boolean isUnlocked;
```

Then when the textview us unlocked by user on long press update the model :

```
insegnamenti.get(position).setIsUnlocked(true); 
updateListViewdata(insegnamenti);// to update your listview
```

your updateListViewdata method should be like below :

```
public void updateListViewData(Insegnamenti updatedInsegnamenti){
this.insegnamenti = updatedInsegnamenti;
notifydatasetchanged();
}
```

Then check the isUnlock flag inside getview() to show updated view.
Hope it helps.